# How to select group of checkboxes with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

MY HTML:

The main checkbox

```
<label class="new-control new-checkbox m-0 checkbox-success" >
    <input type="checkbox" class="new-control-input" onclick="select_section('admin_section')">
</label>
```

There are many of this

```
<div class="pt-2 pb-2">
    <label class="new-control new-checkbox checkbox-success" >
        <input type="checkbox" name="permissions[]" class="admin_section">
        <span class="new-control-indicator"></span>
    </label>
</div>
```

Jquery to check the above group but it does not work!

```
function select_section(value){
    var checkboxe = $('input[class="'+ value +'"]:checkbox');

    if(!checkboxe.prop("checked")) {
        checkboxe.attr('checked', 'checked');
    } else {
        checkboxe.removeAttr('checked');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `data` attributes to hold the target class, then you can use the `checked` status of the main checkbox to set the target ones like so:

```
$('.new-control-input').on('change', function() {
    let cls = '.' + $(this).data('value');
    $(cls).prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

**DEMO**

```js
$('.new-control-input').on('change', function() {
    let cls = '.' + $(this).data('value');
    $(cls).prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="new-control new-checkbox m-0 checkbox-success" >
    <input type="checkbox" class="new-control-input" data-value="admin_section">
</label>
<div class="pt-2 pb-2">
    <label class="new-control new-checkbox checkbox-success" >
        <input type="checkbox" name="permissions[]" class="admin_section">
        <span class="new-control-indicator"></span>
    </label>
</div>
<div class="pt-2 pb-2">
    <label class="new-control new-checkbox checkbox-success" >
        <input type="checkbox" name="permissions[]" class="admin_section">
        <span class="new-control-indicator"></span>
    </label>
</div>
<div class="pt-2 pb-2">
    <label class="new-control new-checkbox checkbox-success" >
        <input type="checkbox" name="permissions[]" class="admin_section">
        <span class="new-control-indicator"></span>
    </label>
</div>
<div class="pt-2 pb-2">
    <label class="new-control new-checkbox checkbox-success" >
        <input type="checkbox" name="permissions[]" class="admin_section">
        <span class="new-control-indicator"></span>
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you but I need to be as function cuz there will be many sections that is one of them and if I do your way then I have to duplicate the code for each group!

Comment: The code will work for all of your different sections. You don't need a function; you just need to change ` data-value="admin_section"` for each section. Just the value of this attribute will need to change for a new section; no more jQuery code will be needed. -

Comment: Thank you so much perfect one!

Answer (score 0):

First, get rid of the inline event handler. Then the following will check/uncheck the `.admin_section` checkboxes when `.new-control-input` is checked/unchecked:

```js
$('.new-control-input').click(function(){
  $('.admin_section').prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="new-control new-checkbox m-0 checkbox-success" >
    <input type="checkbox" class="new-control-input">
</label>

<div class="pt-2 pb-2">
    <label class="new-control new-checkbox checkbox-success" >
        <input type="checkbox" name="permissions[]" class="admin_section">
        <span class="new-control-indicator"></span>
    </label>
</div>
<div class="pt-2 pb-2">
    <label class="new-control new-checkbox checkbox-success" >
        <input type="checkbox" name="permissions[]" class="admin_section">
        <span class="new-control-indicator"></span>
    </label>
</div>
<div class="pt-2 pb-2">
    <label class="new-control new-checkbox checkbox-success" >
        <input type="checkbox" name="permissions[]" class="admin_section">
        <span class="new-control-indicator"></span>
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you but I need to be as function cuz there will be many sections that is one of them and if I do your way then I have to duplicate the code for each group!

Comment: @jamel No you won't. But I can't give you a more generic answer unless you provide a more complete example of what you're dealing with in your question